# Move similar voting badges to the same groups

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, badges, voting-badges

### Context

I'm talking about the [Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) page for each site. There you can see six voting badges:

- *Supporter*
- *Critic*
- *Suffrage*
- *Vox Populi*
- *Civic Duty*
- *Electorate*

### Problem

Every voting badge resides in a separate group and these groups sometimes lie very far from each other:

[image: badges page with the voting badges far apart, an arrow pointing at each]

### Suggestion

Move to three groups: single votes, multiple daily votes, multiple votes:

[image: grouped badges]

---

Also something similar can be applied to bounty badges:

- *Altruist*
- *Benefactor*
- *Investor*
- *Promoter*

Comment: You forgot to mention Electorate and Civic Duty which are also voting badges. I would say either put all six badges (Supporter, Critic, Suffrage, Vox Populi, Civic Duty, Electorate) in the same group or make three groups right next to each other with Supporter and Critic in one, Suffrage and Vox Populi in the second one and Civic Duty and Electorate in the third one.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Totally agree about grouping `Electorate` and `Civic Duty`.

Comment: The badges are clearly deliberately ordered in **alphabetical order**

Comment: @DavidPostill OK, moving voting badges to single or two groups can be achieved without breaking alphabetical order.

Comment: If you are going to propose something as radical as this you should also include Civic Duty, Constituent, Electorate, and Sportsmanship, which are also voting badges. Please try to be consistent ... and you still haven't explained **why** your idea is so wonderful ...

Comment: @DavidPostill `Constituent` is election voting, not post voting, it shouldn't be grouped with any of mentioned here at all. `Sportsmanship` has noting common with any other also except voting. It shouldn't be grouped either. About `Electorate` and `Civic Duty`: they can be grouped to single group as DonaldDuck suggested in his comment. I also like idea of grouping bounty badges as in ZaniXu's answer. **Why?** Similar badges should belong to the same group. That's all.

Comment: Your question clearly says "There you can see four voting badges". There are 8. Please update your question and clarify exactly what you mean by voting. By the way I still think it's a bad idea regardless.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Rewritten question to reflect your idea.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a great idea, to make things less confusing and sort things together. They should also put all the bounty badges together.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer. Do note that here on Meta, you only need 5 rep to comment.

Comment: There wasn't a question to be answered

Comment: @ZaniXu Edited question to add your cool idea about bounty badges.